# Insights before 2010-04-02 are missing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'd like to get Insights data before 2010-04-02, but it seems to be impossible to retrieve via the Graph API or FQL query.  If you make a Graph API request spanning over 2010-04-02 you will get results starting at 2010-04-02 and going forward with the rest simply missing.  Can any one explain this or have a way to get around this limitation?

Here is an example of the problem:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2439131959%2Finsights%2Fapplication_active_users%3Fsince%3D2010-03-28%26until%3D2010-04-10%26date_format%3DY-m-d

There should be results from 2010-03-28 to 2010-04-10, but you only get 2010-04-02 and onwards.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "2439131959/insights/application_active_users/day", 
      "name": "application_active_users", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 172118, 
          "end_time": "2010-04-02"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 177263, 
          "end_time": "2010-04-03"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 176568, 
          "end_time": "2010-04-04"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 190725, 
          "end_time": "2010-04-05"
        }, 

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your insights were a "victim" of this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

> We are deprecating some old insights. These metrics are marked as
>   deprecated throughout this document. After 12/21/2011, data for these
>   metrics won't be available prior to 07/19/2011 -- please download this
>   data before this 12/21/2011. These insights will be completely removed
>   from API after 02/15/2012.

Comment: The only relation between what you've seen and my question is that they're both about missing stats.  However, the stats I'm looking at "daily active users" is not deprecated and most likely will never be.

Comment: Does Facebook advertise they will maintain all your stats from the beginning?  If so, then you have a bug to report.  Or maybe with the deprecation of those items, your data also was inadvertently removed (hence my choice of the word victim).

Comment: No, there is no claim like that.  However that barrier differs if you try to get stats via FQL instead of the Graph API.  The barrier also doesn't change as time goes on (it's not a moving barrier where you can only go back so many days).